# Switch function outputting default instead of desired value

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement

I'm trying to do a simple switch function with the following code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM entries where Venue='Condamine' and Year='2018' and 
Event='$5,000 Novice'  and herd='2' and scratched IN('n','l')  ORDER BY Draw 
ASC";
// Execute the query
$result = mysqli_query($con ,$query);
if (!$result){
    die ("Could not query the database: <br />". mysqli_error());
}
// Change herds
function getherd($catch) { 
    switch($catch) 
    { 
        case '2': 
            return 'Herd Change'; 
        break; 
        default: 
            return 'Damn!'; 
        break; 
    } 
} 
$catch = $row["herd"];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td bgcolor=#FFFFFF><strong> ". getherd($catch) ." </strong></td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=#FFFFFF>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "</tr>";
?>
```

My result is printing out the default value "Damn!" instead of the desired value "Herd Change" what am I doing wrong. I want to print out the words "Herd Change" if the value of the row herd = 2.

Comment: please `var_dump($catch)` before `echo "<tr>"` and check for the result

Answer (score 3):

its most probably a typecasting issue

try

`$catch = string($row["herd"]);` and make sure the $catch is 2

Comment: Thanks I'm now getting this error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str() in /home

Comment: sorry, bro, try the edited ans, i use python so gave the syntax of that. try it

Comment: Use $catch = (string) $row["herd"];
This should work!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be changed as below.

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM entries where Venue='Condamine' and Year='2018' and 
Event='$5,000 Novice'  and herd='2' and scratched IN('n','l')  ORDER BY Draw 
ASC";
// Execute the query
$result = mysqli_query($con ,$query);
if (!$result){
    die ("Could not query the database: <br />". mysqli_error());
}
// Change herds
function getherd($catch) { 
    switch($catch) 
    { 
        case '2': 
            return 'Herd Change'; 
        break;
        default: 
            return 'Damn!'; 
           //Break doesn't require in default case
    } 
}

//here you need to get results set from $result.
$html = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
     $catch = $row["herd"];

     $html += "<tr>";
     $html += "<td bgcolor=#FFFFFF><strong> ". getherd($catch) ." </strong></td>";
     $html += "<td bgcolor=#FFFFFF>&nbsp;</td>";
     $html += "</tr>";  
}
echo $html;
//It will print multiple rows, If query returns multiple rows.
?>
```

Comment: I think you are right!
"$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)"  this line was missing ;-)

Comment: I have tried out Thushan's code and am getting a herd undefined error. However I did add the code while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$herd = $row["herd"]; to my current script. It is actually working but am now getting the error message Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getherd() (previously declared in /home/sqchacom/public_html/nominations/2018_condamine/draws/test.php:144) in /home/sqchacom/public_html/nominations/2018_condamine/draws/test.php on line 144 line 144 is function getherd($herd) {

Comment: I have now added the GROUP BY function this has removed the error and the switch statement is now working. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable $catch contains integer value then use below syntax.

```
switch($catch){
  case 2:
     // your code
  default:
     // your code
}
```

In case of String value do the following,

```
switch($catch){
  case "2":
     // your code
  default:
     // your code
}
```

[Switch case manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

It is not good practice to manually typecast the variable.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but either made no difference

Comment: can you please provide whole code so that I can test?